# Memory leak from client.Do()

Tags: go, memory-leaks

The `getAPIData` function is for getting string of HTML, and it need to be called every 5 seconds. I checked memory usage with the `runtime.ReadMemStats` function.

As the output below shows, the memory goes up slowly but never goes down.

```
Alloc = 1 MiB   TotalAlloc = 2 MiB      Sys = 71 MiB    NumGC = 1
...
Alloc = 3 MiB   TotalAlloc = 4 MiB      Sys = 71 MiB    NumGC = 1
...
Alloc = 3 MiB   TotalAlloc = 6 MiB      Sys = 71 MiB    NumGC = 2
Alloc = 2 MiB   TotalAlloc = 7 MiB      Sys = 71 MiB    NumGC = 3
...
Alloc = 3 MiB   TotalAlloc = 9 MiB      Sys = 71 MiB    NumGC = 3
...
Alloc = 3 MiB   TotalAlloc = 10 MiB     Sys = 71 MiB    NumGC = 4
```

I made sample code of my problem. What should I do to fix that memory leak?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func getAPIData() (string, error) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://google.com/", nil)
    if err != nil {
        //fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return "", err
        //panic(err)
    }
    req.Header.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0")

    client := &http.Client{Timeout: 3 * time.Second}
    resp, err := client.Do(req) // cuase of memory leak
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return "", err
        //panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    bytes, err2 := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err2 != nil {
        fmt.Println(err2.Error())
        return "", err2
        //panic(err)
    }
    return string(bytes), nil
}

func PrintMemUsage() {
    var m runtime.MemStats
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m)

    fmt.Printf("Alloc = %v MiB", bToMb(m.Alloc))
    fmt.Printf("\tTotalAlloc = %v MiB", bToMb(m.TotalAlloc))
    fmt.Printf("\tSys = %v MiB", bToMb(m.Sys))
    fmt.Printf("\tNumGC = %v\n", m.NumGC)
}

func bToMb(b uint64) uint64 {
    return b / 1024 / 1024
}
func main() {
    for range time.Tick(5 * time.Second) {
        _, _ = getAPIData()
        PrintMemUsage()
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not show any leak. `TotalAlloc` is the amount that has been allocated; if some memory is freed, then allocated again, the "total amount allocated" increases. As each allocated object is released, so does the count of frees; the `Alloc` value decreases, but the `TotalAlloc` value does not.

Comment: Since your `Alloc` value holds steady around 3 MiB, there is pretty clearly no actual leak. If TotalAlloc is 10 and Alloc is 3, 7 must have been released along the way.

Comment: understood about totalalloc value. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

May not be the source a memory leak, but when dealing with `http.Client`s the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http) suggest:

> Clients and Transports are safe for concurrent use by multiple
> goroutines and for efficiency should only be **created once and re-used**.

So in you example, update your API signature, to pass in a client:

```
func getAPIData(client *http.Client) (string, error)
```

and move the (single) client creation to `main`:

```
func main() {

    cli := &http.Client{Timeout: 3 * time.Second} // create once ...

    for range time.Tick(5 * time.Second) {
        _, _ = getAPIData(cli)   // ... reuse many times
        PrintMemUsage()
    }
}
```